# i'm a python 3.10 discord.py coder when i try to run the code it gives an error mentioned below the code

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py

this is my python bot unban command code

```
@Sapphire.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    """Unbans a member from the server."""
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user
        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=f"Unbanned {user.mention}", color=0xc700ff))
            unban_embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{user} has been unbanned from this server. | Unbanned by {ctx.author.name}", color=0xc700ff)
            await ctx.send(embed=unban_embed)
            try:
                await user.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=f"You have been unbanned from **{ctx.guild.name}** by **{ctx.author.name}**.", color=0xc700ff))
            except discord.Forbidden:
                pass
            break
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Could not find a banned user with the name {member}.")
```

And when i try to run the command unban it gives me this error:
An error occurred: Command raised an exception: TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression

i expected the code should work in python 3.10 but it didn't

Comment: Which line gives you that error?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Could you please explain what the @Sapphire.command() @commands.has_permissions
refer too. Are they imports or do they refer to other parts of your code

Comment: @Anthony this is how dpy works. The first one creates a command, the second one is a check that is added. There's no need for OP to include this info (like the import) in the post as it's not relevant to the question and can just be found in the docs. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has%20perm#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions

Answer (score 0):

You're using Guild.bans incorrectly. AsyncIterators were removed in 2.0. Read the docs. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#moving-away-from-custom-asynciterator

The docs for Guild.bans even show these examples as well: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=bans#discord.Guild.bans